# pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter: passing dataframe column to define size works in shell but not in code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using column data from a dataframe: when I run a one-line command in the shell, I am able to achieve the desired result (the values in a column of the dataframe define the resulting plot points' size). However, using similar code in a script (in the same environment, on the same machine) does not have the same effect.

I can achieve the desired results in the shell:

```py
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('Agg')
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> df = pd.read_csv('CTRL_to_M5.csv', sep=',')
>>> df.reset_index().plot.scatter('index','logFC',s=df['BenjHoch'],c='FCGroup',colormap='jet')
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f3ffa238438>
```

When translating these commands and running the script I cannot achieve the same results:

```py
def dictToPlots(formattedTopTagsDict):
    """Docstring description of the dictToPlots function.
    """
    for tabName in formattedTopTagsDict.keys():
        if tabName != 'Experimental Design':

            indexedDF = formattedTopTagsDict[tabName].reset_index(drop=True)

            indexedDF.reset_index().plot.scatter('index',
                                                 'logFC',
                                                 s=indexedDF['BenjHoch'],
                                                 c='FCGroup',
                                                 colormap='jet')
            plt.savefig(tabName+'_COLOR_SHAPE.pdf')

    return None
```

Traceback:

```
  File "my_script.py", line 916, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_script.py", line 906, in main
    exactTest(reads, expDes, parseArgs.numTopTags, parseArgs.refGenome)
  File "my_script.py", line 386, in exactTest
    dictToPlots(formattedTopTagsDict, 'genes')
  File "my_script.py", line 832, in dictToPlots
    colormap='jet')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 3516, in scatter
    return self(kind='scatter', x=x, y=y, c=c, s=s, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2942, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1973, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1801, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 251, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 894, in _make_plot
    label=label, cmap=cmap, **self.kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1717, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4032, in scatter
    alpha=alpha
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 880, in __init__
    self.set_sizes(sizes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 853, in set_sizes
    scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Comment: I assume you have not edited the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py` yourself? The stack trace seems to say that `np` was defined as an integer (when it should be `import numpy as np`). (I have no idea of what happens here.)

Comment: I have not edited collections.py at all: I do `import numpy as np` at the beginning of the script, though. Is there a way to cast an int as a scalar? Would that be a solution?

Comment: The problem is not in the values you are passing, but rather the `np` object. The script is configured differently, but it's not clear how. I've seen mistakes in code where one line in the script may say something like `np=5`, which would cause your error. That's not visible in the code you posted tho.

Comment: Lines of code with including "np" (not including comments): ```if not np.isnan(QVC) and QVC < QVCCutoff :```
            ```FC.loc[index] = [np.exp2(row['logFC'])]```
            ```FC.loc[index] = [np.exp2(abs(row['logFC'])) * -1```

Comment: Reading the error I would assume the matplotlib install is broken or you have a file named numpy.py in your folder.

Comment: No numpy.py in folder: uninstalling and re-installing matplotlib and numpy does not fix the problem.

Comment: Try replacing the script by the two-liner `import numpy as np`, `print(np.sqrt(2.0))`, and see what happens. Make sure to execute it the same way (same python environment, same interpreter, same file location etc.).

Comment: @Leporello That works just fine: returns "1.4142135623730951". I've migrated to seaborn and am having a little more success ... have run up against a similar problem, however. The plotting packages are really helpful but they seem pretty finicky to me.